# I use wildcard subdomain in opencart2x and have this No Access-Control-Allow-Origin in header

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

And not understand how fix this problem, web server - apache...

for example:
link.com - all good
sub.link.com - not good, in console error

**Font from origin 'link.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'sub.link.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

i tried add in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

after this remove and add this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>
```

and without .htaccess, I tried add in index.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

BUT NOT WORKING! I think this problem due to because CSS fots files use like

```
...
src:url('icons/fonts/journal-icons.eot');
src:url('icons/fonts/journal-icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
...
```

but I do not understand what I need to do to fix this problem??? (It looked similar questions but did not help)

Comment: please clarify: when you browse sub.link.com, then it wants to load the font from link.com?

Comment: Gavriel yes, correct) how i can do this?

Comment: And all this .htaccess is on link.com, right? And do you see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the responses when you go to link.com?

Comment: or in .htaccess or can be in index.php, no matter how, the main thing that worked, no i don't see header responses) for example http://www.mss.partneris.net/ and http://www.test.mss.partneris.net/ first works correct, second with console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very clear error message in the Chrome javascript console:

```
Font from origin 'http://www.mss.partneris.net' has been blocked from loading
by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. Origin
'http://www.test.mss.partneris.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Add:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>
```

to your apache configuration for **http://www.mss.partneris.net** domain, restart apache, and go to http://www.mss.partneris.net/catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/icons/fonts/journal-icons.woff in your browser or using curl, and see that it has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header. When it does, try again in the browser, and hopefully it will all work well.

Comment: Thanks for answer but not help, in headers i see 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' www.mss.partneris.net/phpinfo.php in this file php code `<?php
  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://test.mss.partneris.net/');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($out); echo '</pre>';
    curl_close($curl);
  } ` error in console It was still present :(

Comment: So if you want to wrap all your font and css, img files with a php go on :) Otherwise add htaccess, 'cause it needs to work for all those files. Php is not a good solution here

Comment: no i don't use php how solution, i add in .htaccess `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>` through php(curl) i only look headers from server ;) and headers have Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" , but errors was still present, what i do wrong?

Comment: This font doesn't have the header: http://www.mss.partneris.net/catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/icons/fonts/journal-icons.woff, nor does this: http://www.mss.partneris.net/catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/icons/fonts/journal-icons.ttf

Comment: maybe the 3 lines in htaccess are in the wrong place. post the whole context of it

Comment: where I just did not put, it does not work ;/, here is my www.mss.partneris.net/phpinfo.php

Comment: will you be so kind and post us the whole htaccess

Comment: sorry i don't know how show on stackoverflow, full my .htaccess, you can see all my settings by **www.mss.partneris.net/htaccess.php** ;) there is one in one that in my .htaccess

Comment: I'd try to put the Header not immediately after the RewriteCond. Put it at the end, after the RewriteRule. Or remove the 3 lines of RewriteCond

Comment: very strange but this code with mod_headers Control-Allow-Origin "*", works on mozilla browser all good, on chrome not work :O

Comment: It's a server side setting, even if you look with curl you should see the header. If it works in FF w/o the header then it's probably still in the cache from a previous experience. Clear the cache, refresh the page, and I bet it'll be the same as on chrome

Comment: ahhh, yes you a right! its browser cache :) thanks. problem solved, your code for .htaccess work! Thanks